# Calculated column issue in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an issue with this below query in calculated column `Cost %`

```
Cost % = Amount/SUM(Amount) * 100
```

SUM(Amount) equals 2599.30 from the data that I have provided.

```
SELECT
    S.Product_Name,
    SPD.UnitPrice,
    SPD.Quantity,
    SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) AS Amount,
    SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) / SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) * 100 as [Cost %]
FROM
    dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD ON
    SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID
GROUP BY
    S.Product_Name,
    SPD.UnitPrice,
    SPD.Quantity
```

The output that I get from this query:

```
Product_Name    UnitPrice   Quantity        Amount  Cost %
pro1             141.55           3         424.65  100.0000000000000
pro2             151.05           3         453.15  100.0000000000000
pro3              40.38           4         161.52  100.0000000000000
pro4              24.08           6         144.48  100.0000000000000
pro5             707.75           2         1415.50 100.0000000000000
```

The output that I am looking for:

```
Product_Name    UnitPrice   Quantity        Amount      Cost %
pro1             141.55           3         424.65      16.33
pro2             151.05           3         453.15      17.43
pro3              40.38           4         161.52      6.21
pro4              24.08           6         144.48      5.55
pro5             707.75           2         1415.50     54.45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should start using table aliases to make your code more readable. Anyway, you should try:

```
SELECT  S.Product_Name, 
        SPD.UnitPrice, 
        SPD.Quantity, 
        SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice Amount,
        (SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice)/(SUM(SPD.Quantity * SPD.UnitPrice) OVER()) * 100 [Cost %]
FROM dbo.Stock_Purchase SP
INNER JOIN dbo.Stock_Purchase_Details SPD
    ON SP.Purchase_ID = SPD.Purchase_ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Store S
    ON SPD.Pro_ID = S.Pro_ID;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i still get the same output from the query i used